# skip certificate validation on "vagrant up"

Tags: curl, vagrant

I'd like to skip the curl certificate validation on `vagrant up` since our proxy MITMs https, so curls' usual SSL cert error pops up.

I tried `vagrant up --insecure puppetlabs/debian-7.8-32-nocm` but that didn't change anything. Next I tried `config.vm.box_download_insecure` and `config.vm.box_download_insecure = "puppetlabs/debian-7.8-32-nocm"` in the Vagrantfile, but alas - no luck.

- What's the URL for `config.vm.box_download_insecure` if I use boxes from atlas?
- Is there another possibility to make curl skip cert checks?

Answer (score 16):

It is expecting a boolean (true/false).

```
config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html

> config.vm.box_download_insecure - If true, then SSL certificates from
>   the server will not be verified. By default, if the URL is an HTTPS
>   URL, then SSL certs will be verified.